# Can git tell me the current line number corresponding to a line number in an old commit?

Tags: git, github

A certain bit of code is in file.py on line 705 in an old commit, from which I created a branch. Since then, master has progressed and file.py has been modified, inserting 50 new lines near the top. Now, in my branch I modify file.py's line 705, and I commit. Then I merge that branch back into master. git automagically knows that my change goes on line 755 in the current file.py. Is there any way I can get it to provide that information without actually making a change? That is, given `oldcommit:file.py:705` I want to produce `master:file.py:755`.

I would prefer a solution using github's web-based tools and API, but if I need to use command line git then that will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the git blame man page:

> -n, --show-number:
>   Show the line number in the original commit (Default: off).

So `git blame -n file.py` will add the line number of the line in the blamed commit.

Comment: That's close, but it only tells me equivalent line numbers from the commit the line was last changed in. I want to be able to get equivalent line numbers from an arbitrary commit.

Comment: @Sparr git annotate takes a revision number, but doesn't have the `-n` option. Maybe `--reverse <commit>` helps.